# How to stop the time remaining from prompting when the game has ended

Tags: java

How to stop the time remaining from prompting when the game has ended

Hi, I'm new to Java and I'm doing my homework on creating a guess-the-number game with three levels in it. Each level will prompt the user a certain time left and he'll only have 3 trys. I have not coded the other levels cause I wanted to solve the time on the first level first. The problem is the time (in seconds) keeps on prompting even though the game is already over.

Also, I'm planning to put a while loop at the very end of this code for level 2, is that a good idea? ... Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Random1 {

    int sec = 0;
    TimerTask task;

    public Random1() {
        this.task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                sec++;
                if (sec == 10) {
                    System.out.println("\t 45 seconds Left!");
                } else if (sec == 45) {
                    System.out.print("\n Times Up!");
                    System.out.println("\n Game Over  !");
                    task.cancel();
                    System.out.print("\n Thank You For Playing :) ");
                }
            }
        };
        Timer mytimer = new Timer();
        mytimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
    }

    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random dice = new Random();
        Random1 t = new Random1(); // called to apply timer

        int number = 1 + dice.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number is: " + number);

        System.out.println("I am thinking of numbers 1 to 6. Guess which number is it?");
        int myAnswer = input.nextInt();

        if (myAnswer == number) {
            System.out.println("Correct! You're a mind reader!");
            count++;
        } else if (myAnswer > number) {
            System.out.println("Wrong! Too high. The number was " + number + ".");
            count++;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong! Too low. The number was " + number + ".");
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("Number of trys: " + count);

        if (count == 3 && myAnswer != number) {
            System.out.println("You've reached the maximum trys. Goodbye!");
        } else if (count < 3 && myAnswer != number) {
            main(new String[] { "I am thinking of numbers 1 to 6. Guess which number it is?" });
        } else if (count <= 3 && myAnswer == number) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You're up for round 2 :) ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should open 'mytimer' as global variable.
And should write:-

```
if (count == 3 && myAnswer != number)
{
    System.out.println("You've reached the maximum trys. Goodbye!");
    mytimer.cancel();
}
```

Worked for Me!!

Hope will Help.